# Doing functional tests on login process

Tags: python, testing, selenium, webdriver, functional-testing

I am doing some tests using selenium on a website. One of the main things that needs to be tested is the sign up/log in process. There are a lot of variables here, and several different network settings that need to be confirmed on setup.

The sign-up process sends a confirmation email link to complete registration.

How would this be tested using Selenium. It seems like I'd need to do the sign-up on the site, then log into my gmail account, and then click the registration link -- is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Instead of logging to Gmail account with Selenium I would access it using POP3 protocol. This would be much more faster and efficient than using Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. The only problem is that there's really no way to tell *when* the email will arrive, and it can take quite some time...

```
def _get_last_message(self):
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD)
    mail.select("inbox")
    result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
    latest_email_id = data[0].split()[-1]
    result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
    raw_email = data[0][1]
    return raw_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with support for this kind of testing.

You can either use some handy builtin [helpers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#email-services)

or the [file backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#file-backend)

Comment: I see -- the point here would be test it on a production server, so I wouldn't be able to modify any backends.